# $\operatorname{Pr}(2T>t)$ is it the same as $\operatorname{Pr}(T>t/2)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Is the $\operatorname{Pr}(2T>t)$ the same as $\operatorname{Pr}(T>t/2)$? Please help. I am unsure of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$T>t/2 \Leftrightarrow 2T>t$, therefore the event $[T>t/2]$ is equivalent to the event $[2T>t]$, hence $\operatorname{Pr}(T>t/2) = \operatorname{Pr}(2T>t)$.